# Normality test giving confusing results

Tags: normal-distribution, python, normality-assumption, scipy

So I was transforming data for machine learning purposes and checking whether I should use the data or log-transform it. In addition to creating histograms I decided to test for normality using `scipy.stats.normaltest`. The data looks as follows.

[image: NORMAL?]

The result of the normality test for this particular data was that the `p-value=0.73`. **Now, I don't claim to be a statistician.** *However...* This does not look like a normal distribution. I tested with a `np.random.normal(0, 1, size=1000)` and it gave something along the lines of `p=0.2` and increasing it to a hundred thousand points gave `p=0.6`. My data holds ~4000 records.

So I must ask. Have I missed something here? Some of the other vaguely log-normally distributed variables gave `p-values` of the order `10^-20` after transforming. Does the value of the Chi^2 test need to be incorporated in some manner?

I'm really lost.

#### Edit:

Running the `normaltest` on the whole `DataFrame` gives different results, which adds to the confusion. It gives the same Chi^2 value, but a halved `p-value` of 0.365...

#### Edit II

Just for the heck of it, this data gives a similar graph but a `p-value` of 0.97. What.

```
>>> a = np.sort(df['col'].values).tolist()[::10]
[0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.1622, 0.1622, 0.1622, 0.1622, 0.1622, 0.1622, 0.1622, 0.1622, 0.1622, 0.1687, 0.1687, 0.1729, 0.1729, 0.1729, 0.1729, 0.1729, 0.1729, 0.1729, 0.1729, 0.1729, 0.1729, 0.1729, 0.1729, 0.1729, 0.1729, 0.1729, 0.1729, 0.1729, 0.1729, 0.1729, 0.1729, 0.1729, 0.1729, 0.1729, 0.1729, 0.1729, 0.2005, 0.2216, 0.2216, 0.2498, 0.2498, 0.2498, 0.2498, 0.2498, 0.2498, 0.2498, 0.2498, 0.2498, 0.2498, 0.2498, 0.2498, 0.2498, 0.2498, 0.2498, 0.2498, 0.2498, 0.2498, 0.2498, 0.3143, 0.3143, 0.3143, 0.3143, 0.3143, 0.3143, 0.3143, 0.48, 0.4854, 0.4854, 0.4854, 0.4854, 0.4854, 0.4854, 0.4854, 0.5078, 0.5078, 0.5078, 0.5078, 0.5078, 0.5078, 0.5078, 0.5078, 0.5078, 0.5078, 0.5078, 0.5078, 0.5078, 0.5078, 0.5078, 0.5078, 0.5078, 0.5328, 0.5328, 0.5328, 0.5328, 0.5328, 0.5328, 0.5328, 0.5328, 0.5328, 0.5328, 0.5328, 0.5328, 0.5328, 0.5328, 0.5328, 0.5328, 0.6496, 0.6496, 0.6496, 0.6496, 0.6496, 0.6496, 0.6496, 0.6496, 0.6496, 0.6496, 0.6496, 0.6496, 0.6496, 0.6496, 0.6496, 0.6496, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.912, 0.912, 0.912, 0.912, 0.912, 0.912, 0.912, 0.912, 0.912, 0.912, 0.912]

>>> from scipy.stats import normaltest
>>> normaltest(a)
NormaltestResult(statistic=0.05292848970575527, pvalue=0.9738828645381232)

>>> from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
>>> plt.hist(a) # Results in a similar graph to above
```

Comment: I suspect you might be mis-applying the test: assuming these bars represent counts of data plotted on the horizontal axis, there's no way any test of Normality will fail to reject that hypothesis.  However, a log transformation won't cure that problem.  Thus, you might be asking a fruitless question in the first place.

Comment: @whuber I'm not saying this was the data I applied the log transform to. Yes they represent the counts. It's a very simple way I'm calling the function. I have a column inside a dataframe with all valid values and the normality test function takes one input.

Comment: But that's *exactly* what you are saying!  If these aren't the data you are concerned about, then why are you displaying this plot??  Please clarify how you are applying the normality test.  Give a *small* reproducible example.

Comment: @whuber Allow me to citate: `Some of the other vaguely log-normally distributed variables gave p-values of the order 10^-20 after transforming.` That is to say: the normality test gives small p-values even for distributions resembling a normal one. But I'll add the code.

Comment: Yes: that's precisely how such a test should behave.  With large amounts of data, it's almost impossible for any real dataset to look normal, so a decent test will detect the (tiny) departures from normality.  That's one of many reasons why your line of inquiry seems to be of little value.

Comment: @whuber Then how come this obviously not normally distributed data gives such a *high* value?

Comment: Here's a simpler way to produce an essentially-equivalent dataset:
`np.hstack([np.full(c, i) for i, c in enumerate([128, 0, 58, 7, 0, 41, 16, 0, 0, 167])])`, which just scales everything up and rounds. Either the skewness and kurtosis tests [used here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.normaltest.html) are surprisingly bad in this case, or there's a bug in `scipy.stats`; it seems that you're calling the function correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's a bug in scipy.stats.normaltest, specifically in scipy.stats.kurtosistest (Scipy 1.1.0).  The data are clearly non-normal, and numerous tests correctly indicate that (ps<.05, see examples in R below).  I've reported the bug.

**Code and Details:**

```
library(moments)
library(nortest)
x=c(0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.1622, 0.1622, 0.1622, 0.1622, 0.1622, 0.1622, 0.1622, 0.1622, 0.1622, 0.1687, 0.1687, 0.1729, 0.1729, 0.1729, 0.1729, 0.1729, 0.1729, 0.1729, 0.1729, 0.1729, 0.1729, 0.1729, 0.1729, 0.1729, 0.1729, 0.1729, 0.1729, 0.1729, 0.1729, 0.1729, 0.1729, 0.1729, 0.1729, 0.1729, 0.1729, 0.1729, 0.2005, 0.2216, 0.2216, 0.2498, 0.2498, 0.2498, 0.2498, 0.2498, 0.2498, 0.2498, 0.2498, 0.2498, 0.2498, 0.2498, 0.2498, 0.2498, 0.2498, 0.2498, 0.2498, 0.2498, 0.2498, 0.2498, 0.3143, 0.3143, 0.3143, 0.3143, 0.3143, 0.3143, 0.3143, 0.48, 0.4854, 0.4854, 0.4854, 0.4854, 0.4854, 0.4854, 0.4854, 0.5078, 0.5078, 0.5078, 0.5078, 0.5078, 0.5078, 0.5078, 0.5078, 0.5078, 0.5078, 0.5078, 0.5078, 0.5078, 0.5078, 0.5078, 0.5078, 0.5078, 0.5328, 0.5328, 0.5328, 0.5328, 0.5328, 0.5328, 0.5328, 0.5328, 0.5328, 0.5328, 0.5328, 0.5328, 0.5328, 0.5328, 0.5328, 0.5328, 0.6496, 0.6496, 0.6496, 0.6496, 0.6496, 0.6496, 0.6496, 0.6496, 0.6496, 0.6496, 0.6496, 0.6496, 0.6496, 0.6496, 0.6496, 0.6496, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.9119, 0.912, 0.912, 0.912, 0.912, 0.912, 0.912, 0.912, 0.912, 0.912, 0.912, 0.912)

pList <- list()
pList$ShapiroWilk <- shapiro.test(x)$p.value
pList$ShapiroFrancia <- sf.test(x)$p.value
pList$AndersonDarling <- ad.test(x)$p.value
pList$KolmSmirLill <- lillie.test(x)$p.value
pList$PearsonChiSq <- pearson.test(x)$p.value
pList
```

**P-values:**

Shapiro-Wilk
1.572961e-23

Shapiro-Francia
2.64774e-20

Anderson-Darling
3.7e-24

Kolmogorov-Smirnov (Lilliefors version)
9.468351e-83

Pearson Chi Squared
0

Comment: I now suspect that the Python function is the real problem. I programmed the D'Agostino omnibus test by hand in R, and it gave a p of approximately 0. I verified the R function's accuracy using the D'Agostino et al. example dataset (1990, pg. 138).  This may take a while, but I'll try to fix the post..

Comment: Results should be z.skew=-0.2300619, z.kurt=46.98108, chisq= 2207.275, and p=0.

There is a part of the formula that's prone to computation errors.  Eq 19 in https://www.ohio.edu/plantbio/staff/mccarthy/quantmet/D'Agostino.pdf involves a cube-root of a negative number (negative for the dataset in this question), and that tripped up R's default exponent function, so maybe the same issue happens in Python?

Comment: The bug is definitely in scipy.stats.kurtosistest located in lines of code attempting to replace  negative numbers prior to taking the cube-root.

Comment: I've updated it, and reported the bug: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/9033.  I'm a Python noob, so maybe someone who's more familiar can come up with a better solution that what I've proposed.

Comment: Wow, awesome that the question generated such attention!

Comment: Very nice piece of detective work.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the negative kurtosis and other details, Nick. My original answer was way off, and I wouldn’t have noticed without your comments.

Answer (score 1):

Tha accepted answer from @Anthony makes the main point: your data have tickled a bug in the software you used.

This is a bundle of extra comments using the sample given in **Edit II** as a sandbox.

As in the distribution histogram shown in the question for other data, you have a spiky, roughly U-shaped distribution. A logarithmic transformation will not help with such a distribution. It will just make it look and be a worse fit to a normal. The spikes will remain spikes. Here is a graph of the distribution.

[image]

There should be a story behind the repeated values: in a sample of 417, you have only a small number of distinct values.

```
   whatever |      Freq.     Percent        Cum.
------------+-----------------------------------
      .0001 |        128       30.70       30.70
      .1622 |          9        2.16       32.85
      .1687 |          2        0.48       33.33
      .1729 |         25        6.00       39.33
      .2005 |          1        0.24       39.57
      .2216 |          2        0.48       40.05
      .2498 |         19        4.56       44.60
      .3143 |          7        1.68       46.28
        .48 |          1        0.24       46.52
      .4854 |          7        1.68       48.20
      .5078 |         17        4.08       52.28
      .5328 |         16        3.84       56.12
      .6496 |         16        3.84       59.95
      .9119 |        156       37.41       97.36
       .912 |         11        2.64      100.00
------------+-----------------------------------
      Total |        417      100.00
```

That aside, for these data I get the following results for moment-based statistics in Stata. The definitions used (on which a Gaussian/normal would have skewness 0 and kurtosis 3) are documented on p.9 of 
[this section in the Stata manuals](https://www.stata.com/manuals/rsummarize.pdf).

Other formulas exist but for this sample size they shouldn't make that much difference.

```
 ----------------------------------------------------------
  n = 417 |       mean          SD    skewness    kurtosis
----------+-----------------------------------------------
 whatever |      0.473       0.398      -0.027       1.243
----------------------------------------------------------
```

Some people like to work with so-called excess kurtosis, subtracting 3.  Here that would be $−$1.757.

In terms of kurtosis the example data here are clearly non-normal. Any test based on skewness and kurtosis should therefore reject a null of normality. For context, minimum possible kurtosis is 1 (excess kurtosis $−$2); that minimum is attainable if half the data are equal to a maximum and half equal to a minimum (e.g. probability of 0 and of 1  both 0.5). Kurtosis just above 1 is expected for a U-shaped distribution, as here.

How best to treat such data depends on knowing more about how they were produced and your goals.

Comment: Yep, thanks, although the question wasn't really on whether I should use the log transform or not. But I appreciate it. The fact that the data contained equal values was a result of a round operation - purely for not sharing the real data. That's also why the data was only apx. a tenth of the original size of the histogram.

Comment: Glad it helped. Given this comment, I have to wonder why you started "So I was transforming data for machine learning purposes and checking whether I should use the data or log-transform it."

Comment: Yeah, I guess it was unnecessary, but I felt like giving at least some context for the normality test.